# Duplicate existing table

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I have created a table in a LibreOffice Write document. I want to duplicate the table in the same document and make a few small changes in the duplicate. The table is large and using the mouse to select the table doesn't seem to be an option. If I choose "Select All", only one cell is selected rather than the entire table. So, I can't find a way to select the entire table and duplicate it. What is a good way to duplicate an existing table?

Answer (score 2):

#### I can't find a way to select the entire table

1. Place the cursor in a table cell
2. To select the entire table do one of the following:

   - Menu > "Table" > "Select" > "Table", or
   - <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>s</kbd>, <kbd>t</kbd>, or
   - Right-click "Select" > "Table"
3. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to copy the table
4. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to paste the table elsewhere in your document